# AT90CAN128 iocanxx.h vector numbers

Tags: microcontroller, c

The vector numbers in [this header](https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/avr-libc/blob/master/avr-libc/include/avr/iocanxx.h) do not match the vector numbers in the manual [AT90CAN128 doc7679 pdf](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc7679.pdf) Section 8.1
They appear to be one position out
Can anyone advise on which is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484365/why-the-number-of-vector-of-int0-is-1-not-2-as-datasheet

Comment: @Huisman That seems to be the answer. Post it and I'll upvote it

Comment: Nah, then I would be taking credit for what other wizkids have done. Moreover, although I know it should be something like that answer, I wouldn't know *exactly* what I was talking about.

Comment: Instead of keeping this duplicate you could simply delete it. ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee I think that would be a bad idea because it is not a duplicate on EESE, and it is a question concerning firmware

Comment: Oh, I see. I am jumping between both sites as I have accounts on both so I didn't really notice. Sorry. Then, would you like to write an answer yourself and mark it? Just to let searching users see that the question has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [this question is closely related to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484365/why-the-number-of-vector-of-int0-is-1-not-2-as-datasheet) on StackOverflow. Anyway, the bottom line appears to be that it doesn't matter - just use the headers/libraries provided by AVR if you don't want the full explanation